Completeness of sequence sapce w.r.t. supremum norm, what am I missing?
The proof that $l^\infty$ w.r.t. the supremum-norm is complete, typically relies on the completeness of the underlying field.
That is a Cauchy sequence $x^{(n)} \in l^\infty$ gives rise to sequence where each coordinate $x^{(n)}_i$ is Cauchy in a given field $K$, that is there exists a $x_i\in K$ s.t. $x^n_i\rightarrow x_i$ in $K$, now one defines $x:=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. It then remains to show two things

$x\in l^{\infty}$
$x^n \rightarrow x \text{ in } l^\infty$

I have a question about the second part.
The proof I am aware of uses that $x^n$ is Cauchy in $l^\infty$, thus for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n,m\geq N$: $|x_i^n-x_i^m|\leq \epsilon$. Using the convergence of coordinates for the same $\varepsilon$ we can also find an $N_2=N_2(i)$ s.t. for all $m(\varepsilon,i)=m\geq N_2$ $|x_i^m-x_i|\leq m$. Thus for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ then for any $n,m\geq N$
$$|x_i^n-x_i|\leq |x_i^n-x_i^m|+|x_i^m-x_i|\leq 2\varepsilon$$
one then concludes the proof by taking the supremum over all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ as the RHS doesn't depend on $i$ (but in my impression $N$ does depend on $i$).
However, if I look at the $\sup_{i \in\mathbb{N}} |x_i^m-x_i|$ I cannot guarantee the existence of a finite $m$ as $m$ depends on the coordinate $i$, furthermore $N$ also depends on $i$.
What am I missing, where have I gone wrong?

$m$ does not depend on the coordinate $i$, $m$ depends solely on the sequence in $l^\infty$.

I can see how that is the case for first the first inequality in the triangle inequality, but how does it follow for the second inequality, respectively how can we decude that $N_2$ is independent of $i$? We could choose $N_2=N_1$ but this doesn't guarantee us the inequality we want, or does it and if so why?

Somewhat partial answer: One possible idea behind having $N_2$ not depend on the coordinate $i$ in the case $K = \mathbb{R}$ is to not blindly use the convergence of the sequences coordinate by coordinate and instead observe the following using the fact the overall sequence is Cauchy for the second line:
$$\begin{cases}x_i = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_i^n \in [\inf_{n \geq N_1} x_i^n, \sup_{n \geq N_1} x_i^n]\\
\forall i,\,\, \sup_{n \geq N_1} x_i^n - \inf_{n \geq N_1} x_i^n \leq \varepsilon\end{cases}$$
by approaching the $\sup$ and the $\inf$ arbitrarily closely with actual elements from the $x^n$s.
This will imply that you can use $N = N_2 = N_1$ since you'll have:
$$\forall i,\,\forall n \geq N, \quad |x^n_i - x_i| \leq \varepsilon$$
Of course, this line of thought won't work with all fields, although I'm sure you could find a way to replace the prior observation without relying on suprema or infima of elements of the field $K$ since they won't exist for e.g. $\mathbb{C}$, but I felt like this was slightly too long for me to keep as a comment.

Thank you, this has been helpful. I did suspect that one has to use the Cauchy property of the overall sequence, as done here and I suspect that is what most textbooks explicitly mean, but I was suprised to not find it written down as detailed as you have done here.
